# Explanation for a part of this proof about the existence of a subgroup isomorphic to the quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

My question is about an exercise and its solution from a Chinese textbook *Introduction to Modern Algebra* (《近世代数引论》), which I translate into English as follows so that everyone will understand:

**1.10.7** $\,$ Assume that $H$ is a subgroup of a finite abelian group $A$, prove that there exists a subgroup of $A$ isomorphic to $A/H$.

Proof: Write $A=G_1\oplus\dots\oplus G_m$, where $G_i$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $A$ for $i=1,\dots,m$. By **Exercise 1.9.5**$^{[1]}$ we know
$$H=H_1\oplus\dots\oplus H_m,\,H_i=H\cap G_i,\,1\leq i\leq m.$$
$\\$Since$$A/H\cong G_1/H_1\oplus\dots\oplus G_m/H_m,$$
it suffices to prove the existence of  a subgroup of $G_i$ isomorpic to $G_i/H_i$. That is, without loss of generality, from now we assume $|A| = p^n,n\geq 1,|H|=p^m,m\leq n$.

By the structure theorem of abelian $p$-groups we know
$$A=\mathbb{Z}_{p^{r_{\,1}}}\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{r_{\,t}}},\,\,\,\,H=\mathbb{Z}_{p^{s_{\,1}}}\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{s_{\,t}}},$$
$\\$where $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{r_{\,i}}}\leq\mathbb{Z}_{p^{s_{\,i}}},1\leq i\leq t,r_1+\dots+r_t=n,s_1+\dots+s_t=m$, where $r_i$ are positive integers and $s_i$ are nonnegative integers with $s_i\leq r_i$. Thus $$A/H\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^{r_{\,1}-s_{\,1}}}\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{r_{\,t}-s_{\,t}}}\leq A.$$ (End of proof)$^{[2]}$

**My question is about the part where $A$ is assumed to be a $p$-group.** I realized that, given an arbitrary decomposition of $A$, there does not always exist a decomposition of $H$ compatible to that of $A$.

As a counterexample, set $A=\mathbb{V}=\{(1),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ and $H=\{(1),(12)(34)\}$. Denote by $A_1$ and $A_2$ respectively the subgroups $\{(1),(13)(24)\}$ and $\{(1),(14)(23)\}$, we know $A=A_1\oplus A_2$, but there cannot be $H_1\leq A_1$ and $H_2\leq A_2$ such that $H=H_1\oplus H_2$ because both $H\cap A_1$ and $H\cap A_2$ are $\{(1)\}$.

I wonder if we can choose a particular decomposition of $A$ such that a compatible decomposition of  $H$ always exists? Or maybe the author actually mean $H\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p^{s_{\,1}}}\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{s_{\,t}}}$ instead of $H=\mathbb{Z}_{p^{s_{\,1}}}\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{s_{\,t}}}$
in order that $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{r_{\,i}}}\leq\mathbb{Z}_{p^{s_{\,i}}}$? It seems that if any of the assertions above is true then the conclusion follows, but I can prove neither of them. Can anyone show me if the above two assertions can be proved or disproved? If the above two assertion is not the case, is there a way to correct or improve the proof so that it will work out? Thanks in advance!

**Remark**

$[1]$ which asserts that if $G=G_1\oplus\dots\oplus G_m$, and if given any pair of $i,j,1\leq i\lt j\leq n,|G_i|$ and $|G_j|$ are relatively prime, then any subgroup $H$ of $G$ is direct product of its subgroups $H\cap G$.

$[2]$ The original Chinese texts of the exercise and the proof are as follows:

[image]

Comment: The argument I tried to prove in the edit is too strong that it does not always hold. Otherwise, it follows that for every subgroup H of A, H is a direct summand of A, which is absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT (different argument):
Suppose $A\cong C_{p^{a_1}}\times\ldots\times C_{p^{a_n}}$, $B\cong C_{p^{b_1}}\times\ldots\times C_{p^{b_m}}$ and $B\le A$. Without loss of generality, let $a_1\ge\ldots\ge a_n$ and $b_1\ge\ldots\ge b_m$.
As far as I understand, you are asking for a proof of $b_i\le a_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$. Lets argue by induction on $|A|$. If $|A|=1$, we are done. Thus, let $|A|>1$. Since $B$ has $p^m$ elements of order $p$ and $A$ has $p^n$ such elements, we obtain $m\le n$. It is easy to see that $\mho(B)=\{x^p:x\in B\}\cong C_{p^{b_1-1}}\times\ldots\times C_{p^{b_m-1}}$ and similarly for $\mho(A)$. Since $\mho(B)\le\mho(A)$ and $|\mho(A)|<|A|$, we obtain $b_i-1\le a_i-1$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$ by induction. The claim follows.

Comment: Thanks. I apologize that I still failed to make my question clear. Actually I know if we show there exists $b_i\leq a_i$ such that $H\cong C_{p^{b_{\,i}}}\oplus\dots\oplus C_{p^{b_{\,n}}}$, then the conclustion follows. What I cannot prove is why $H$ can be expressed in that way.

Comment: i.d., given a decomposition $A= C_{p^{a_{\,1}}}\oplus\dots\oplus C_{p^{a_{\,n}}}$, how can we show the existence of the decomposition $H= C_{p^{b_{\,1}}}\oplus\dots\oplus C_{p^{b_{\,n}}}$ such that $b_i\leq a_i$?

Comment: Consider the subgroup $\mho(H)=\{x^p:x\in H\}$. Apply induction to $\mho(H)\le\mho(A)$.

Comment: Could you please write a detailed proof for me? I still cannot figure it out.

Comment: Yes, tomorrow ...

Comment: Thank you for your patience. There is no hurry.

Comment: It's done (I just edited my answer)

Comment: Really appreciate for your patience. I've deleted the comments and part of my question about my misunderstanding of your hints to make this post more concise and clear.